# Why is my game object generated by a custom Unity editor script missing its sprite?

Tags: unity, c#

I have a number of sprites that I generate outside of Unity.  I'd like to automate the process of importing these sprites into Unity as fully-configured game objects.  I'm trying to do this through a Unity editor script, but I'm having some difficulty.  When I run my script, my game object is saved as a `.prefab` as expected.  However, the `Sprite` I'm assigning to my game object's `SpriteRenderer` component is missing:

[image: Unity screenshot]

In my script, I'm assigning my `SpriteRenderer`'s `sprite` property to a `Sprite` object that I dynamically create in the script.  Here's the relevant excerpt from my editor script:

```
GameObject gameObject = new GameObject(fileName);

SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer = gameObject.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

// texture size will be replaced during the LoadImage() call
Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
texture.LoadImage(File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(generatedOutputPath, fileName + ".png")));

spriteRenderer.sprite = Sprite.Create(
    texture, 
    new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, texture.width, texture.height),
    new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f)
);

PrefabUtility.CreatePrefab("Assets/Prefabs/" + fileName + ".prefab", gameObject);
DestroyImmediate(gameObject);
```

I can verify through logging that the image path to my `.png` is correct and that the `Texture2D` and `Sprite` objects seem to be instantiated correctly.  For example, I can do this:

```
// logs "580" as expected
Debug.Log(texture.width);
```

What am I doing wrong?  How can I save this game object as a `.prefab` without losing its sprite information?

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem is that the texture can't be serialized. It's loaded from an arbitrary location and thus doesn't exist in the asset path, so Unity can't create a reference to deserialize later.

Comment: Have you tried actually instantiating the prefab to see if it works? Hints [here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/prefab-created-at-runtime-is-missing-sprite-reference-original-object-is-not.219939/) that talk about using `PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab` when later creating the prefab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  I needed to first copy my images into the `Assets/Resources` directory, and then use `Resources.Load<Sprite>("path/to/sprite/here")` to load my `Sprite` instance (instead of loading them from an arbitrary location on the file system).  Here's my updated script:

```
// "files" is a List<string> of file names to load as Sprites.
// first, copy each image to the "Assets/Resources/Sprites" directory
files.ForEach(fileName => {
    File.Copy(
        Path.Combine(generatedOutputPath, fileName + ".png"),
        Path.Combine("Assets/Resources/Sprites", fileName + ".png"),
        true
    );
});

// refresh our AssetsDatabase since we made changes.
AssetDatabase.Refresh();

// for each file, create a new GameObject to hold the loaded Sprite
files.ForEach(fileName => {
    GameObject gameObject = new GameObject(fileName);
    SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer = gameObject.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    spriteRenderer.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/" + fileName);
    PrefabUtility.CreatePrefab("Assets/Prefabs/" + fileName + ".prefab", gameObject);
    DestroyImmediate(gameObject);
});
```

A big thanks to Draco18s and Byte56 for their comments, which pointed me in the right direction.  The example script in [this write-up](http://incd021.com/pyxel-edit-first-impression-and-importer/) also helped me get my script straightened out.